# How to make sure that you return something in recursive functions?

Tags: java

I am writing a simple GCD functions and I am sure that it will always return something as I have written a return statement in an if. How do I make sure that the program does not end in compilation error. Is it ok to write another return statement at the end?

```
private static int gcd(long a, long b){
  if(b==0) 
      return (int)a;
  else{
      a=a%b;
      gcd(b,a);
  }
  //I want to avoid the next statement as I think it is redundant, 
  //but the compiler does not allow me to skip it.
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can and should throw an exception if normal execution means it should never reach that final return statement.

Comment: There is a @CheckReturnValue annotation, which [Google's errorprone](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/CheckReturnValue) will use to ensure you use the return value.

Comment: @AndyTurner not at all what he's asking

Comment: @Michael or just don't add the "unreachable" statement, and the compiler will complain if you haven't returned before the end of the method.

Comment: You wouldn't need that `return 0;` if you wouldn't ignore the result of nested `gcd` calls.

Comment: Hi Michael, Andy,
The confusion that I have is, I understand we should basically write the if statement first which would catch the condition when you want to end the recursion and start returning values, but in that case, the compiler I guess wants me to write another return statement below the recursion call so that it satisfies the scenario that there is a return statement eventually in the function.

Comment: When a recursive function calls itself, it almost **always** wants to return the value that results from that call. E.g., when calling `gcd` from within `gcd`, return the result: `return gcd(b, a);` (**Note:** I haven't checked the logic of the function. It's critical that a recursive function have a get-out clause. I think your `if` does it, but...)

Answer (score 1):

On the else branch you probably intend to use `return gcd(b, a)`, instead of simply calling `gcd(b, a)` and not using its result.

In this way there is no need to use the `return 0` at the end, because all possible branches return something now.

Comment: Thanks! I was making a mistake by not using the value return by the recursive call to return back from this current call as well. Now I understand the mistake and it works too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a return statement in every possible end of every nonvoid function. This is not something you can avoid. So if you have an if-statement with a return statement inside of it, you will also need to have a return statement in every other end of the function, because if the condition is not fulfilled, your function would not be accepted by the compiler, since the caller expects a return.

There are though, if you need it, possibilities to not return 0 like you have it in your function now. There are generally 2 possibilities:

1. return null (highly unrecommended)

If you return null, it is like you are returning nothing to the caller. In this case the caller has to know, that the function may return null if some condition is met.

2. throw an exception

You can throw an exception if some unwanted condition for your function is present. It is the more recommended possibility, since the caller will then have to acknowledge that the function was called in a bad state and the code of the caller will then have to include some try-catch instead of if(returnedObject == null)

EDIT:

With your comment I have now understood what your confusion was and I can see the problem now. You want to make a recursive call, but what would happen with your current state is:

Either you will meat the stop condition and then return a casted to an int:

```
if (b == 0)
```

Or you would come to the else block and make the recursive call:

```
gcd(b,a);
```

but then you wont return the result of the recursive call, hence in the second outcome of your function you will have no return and hence the compiler shows you the error. Since you want to return the result of the recursive calls, as I assume, you will have to change

```
gcd(b,a);
```

to

```
return gcd(b,a);
```

Then your compiler should be fine, because the if and the else block both provide a return statement.

Comment: Don't even mention option 1. It's terrible practice. Use Optional<Foo> or throw an exception.

Comment: You're welcome! Certainly check them out, as they are very important in many ways

Answer (score 0):

First you miss something, which will solve your problem, it's `return` the value in the `else gcd`

```
private static int gcd(long a, long b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return (int) a;
    else {
        a = a % b;
        return gcd(b, a);
    }
}
```

---

You can also remove the `else` part like this (because of the `return`)

```
private static int gcd(long a, long b) {
    if (b == 0) 
        return (int) a;
    a = a % b;
    return gcd(b, a);
}

// - - - - - - - - - - OR - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

private static int gcd(long a, long b) {
    if (b != 0){
        a = a % b;
        return gcd(b, a);
    }
  return (int) a;
}
```

Comment: Those aren't reductions of the code, they're just different ways of expressing exactly the same thing. They are no objective improvement over the way OP expressed it.